# How to convert this short if statement in Laravel into a long one?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a short if else statement that I'm having trouble converting into a full one.

The reason is I would like to include some html inside instead of just text.

```
Auth::user()->likes()->where('status_id', $status->id)->first() ? Auth::user()->likes()->where('status_id', $status->id)->first()->like == 1 ? 'You like this post' : 'Like' : 'Like'
```

Please note that I am doing this inside a blade template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should translate to:

```
if(Auth::user()->likes()->where('status_id', $status->id)->first()){
    if(Auth::user()->likes()->where('status_id', $status->id)->first()->like == 1){
        $var = 'You like this post';
    }else{
        $var = 'Like';
    }
}else{
    $var = 'Like';
}
```

Added `$var` to save the value, without it it doesn't make much sense.

Also, as it is, you could combine the if constructs via `and`

```
if(Auth::user()->likes()->where('status_id', $status->id)->first() 
        && Auth::user()->likes()->where('status_id', $status->id)->first()->like == 1){
    $if = 'You like this post';
}else{
    $if = 'Like';
}
```

Comment: I am doing this inside a blade template, the second snippet works but I have to reload the page to view the results. I guess I need to modify my javascript as well to get the results without page reload.

Answer (score 2):

```
$likes = Auth::user()->likes()->where('status_id', $status->id)->first();

if ($likes && $likes->like == 1) {
    $text = 'You like this post';
}
else {
    $text = 'Like';
}
```

Comment: This is returning a json array `{"id":39,"user_id":14,"status_id":21,"created_at":"2016-07-30 20:49:35","updated_at":"2016-07-30 20:49:35","like":1} You like this post`

Comment: @Halnex You must provide more context in your questions or it will be impossible to help you.